# $OSFONTDIR on OSX

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive, mac, luaotfload

I've been playing around with `TeXLive 13 pretest` on OSX, and I've been unable to tell `luatex/luaotfload` where to look for fonts.

I know that `luaotfload` will look in the standard font directories and that there is the variable `$OSFONTDIR`. What I try to do is make it look for the directory `~/Library/FontExplorerX` where the `Linotype FontExplorer` stores its fonts.

When I try `export OSFONTDIR=/Users/simi/FontExplorerX//:$OSFONTDIR`, `luaotfload-tool --update` will scan the directory and make the fonts available. Unfortunately, this doesn't stick.

Where can I tell TL permanently where `$OSFONTDIR` is? I've read that putting the line `OSFONTDIR= /Users/simi/FontExplorerX//` in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf` should do the trick, but this seems to have no effect. Neither `luaotfload-tool` nor `kpsewhich` seem to care about this setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution, if you are using the Bash shell, is to add

`export OSFONTDIR=/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/`

to your `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: I'm using bash, but I wonder whether this really sets the variable globally. For example, if I run `lualatex` with `TeXShop` and `luaotfload-tool` will start to rescan the font directories, will it use this setting?

Comment: @Simifilm According to http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html, this setting may override the global settings.

Comment: Is there conceptually any difference between `.bash_profile` and `.profile`?

Comment: @Simifilm Please, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment