# LuaLaTeX can’t find fonts organised by FontExplorer X

Tags: fonts, luaotfload

I’m trying to switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX but unfortunately the latter doesn’t seem to find fonts that are organised with [FontExplorer X](https://www.fontexplorerx.com), while XeTeX hasn’t any problems. The following example works fine with XeLaTeX but with LuaLaTeX I only get the `font-not-found` error message:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !-TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

When I change the font to Arial (which is in anther font folder, see below) LuaLaTeX works.

After reading [$OSFONTDIR on OSX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117129/4918) I tried to add the FontExplorer folder to `$ODFONTDIR` but without success:

```
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ export OSFONTDIR="/Users/Tobi/FontExplorer X/Font Library/":$OSFONTDIR
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ echo $OSFONTDIR
/Users/Tobi/FontExplorer X/Font Library/:
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ luaotfload-tool --update
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ luaotfload-tool --find="Arial"
luaotfload | resolve : Font "Arial" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf"
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro"
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font Minion Pro not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "Minion Pro" in index.
luaotfload | resolve : Hint: use the --fuzzy option to display suggestions.
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$
```

<sup>See edit history of this post for the version with escaped space instead of double quotes.</sup>

I know that XeTeX and LuaTeX handle font loading differently but **how can I make LuaTeX work with fonts saved in `/Users/Tobi/FontExplorer X/Font Library/`?**

---

I’m working with MacTeX alias TeX Live 2016 (up to date) and FontExplorer X Pro 5.5.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

```
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)
```

```
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ lualatex -v
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
```

---

**Information of the fonts**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have a mac, but your handling of the space in the path looks odd. Why don't you quote it? `"/Users/Tobi/FontExplorer X/Font Library/"`

Comment: The space is escaped (that’s the way macOS does it if I drag a folder in the terminal app). However the result with double quotes is exactly the same … (see edit)

Comment: And what happens if you use the full path (that means add the M/Minion Pro/)?

Comment: That `$OSFONTDIR` isn't searched recursively was an issue in the past, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275072/29873

Comment: @Tobi Setting `$OSFONTDIR` to `$HOME/FontExplorer X/Font Library//` (two slashes at the end) seems to work.  At least `luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro"` finds the font now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Kpathsea` searches a given path recursively if it ends with two slashes (`//`). Accordingly

```
export OSFONTDIR="$HOME/FontExplorer X/Font Library//"
luaotfload-tool --update
```

should work. And indeed

```
luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro"
```

yields

```
luaotfload | resolve : Font "Minion Pro" found! 
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/Users/<username>/FontExplorer X/Font Library/M/Minion Pro/MinionPro-Regular.otf"
```

compiling your MWE works also

[image]

and `pdffonts`returns

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
YSSVEJ+MinionPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I already tried your suggestion after you commented but forgot to answer O:-) However it works finde now. Thanks!